# Version application parameter in tomcat's manager

Tags: tomcat, application

where does tomcat read the "version" value it shows for the deployed applications in the manager application from? I've searched for such parameter in web.xml but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 7 checks the war filename for version:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming

Does not seem to work when using the ANT deployer.

Answer (score 0):

Its in a properties file - loaded as a ResourceBundle - the properties file to look for is
org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties